# Change cell value based on the cell's background color in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I would like to change the cell value (in this case to add text) based on the cell's background color. For example, if the cell's background color is green (#62a84f) as in the picture attached, I would like to automatically insert text "g" in the cell.
[Please see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWU8t.png)
I found the following script but cannot figure out how to get it working:

```html
function myFunction() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Prosinec+Leden");

  var data1 = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();  //2D array of sheet1 cell values
  var bg;

  for(var i=1; i<data1.length; i++)
  {
    bg = sheet1.getRange(?).getBackground();
    if(bg == "#62a84f")  
    {
      sheet1.getRange(?).setValue("x");  //Set value in corresponding row of sheet1
    }    
  }
}
```

*Little background info - I work in an elementary school where we evaluate the progress of our pupils every week and it would save us a lot of work to have this script work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

While that's might not be an issue, the color `"#62a84f"` you selected is not one of the default colors in the color picker menu. In order to test the following code, I used the default `#34a853`:

[image]

But if you are sure that your color is indeed `"#62a84f"` then go ahead and use that and change the relevant part of my code to your case.

---

I used double [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over every cell in the `rng`. The bigger the range the slower the performance of the code. I would highly advice you to use some specific range and not the whole data range.

Namely, you might want to replace:

`const rng = sheet1.getDataRange();` with `const rng = sheet1.getRange('B2:D10');`

assuming that you want to check for green cells in the range `'B2:D10'`.

Another reason you would want to use this approach is that you may have some green cells with no content outside of the `DataRange` and therefore your range won't contain these cells. So think carefully what is your scenario and choose the method that suits you the best.

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Prosinec+Leden");
  const rng = sheet1.getDataRange();
  const colors = rng.getBackgrounds();
  const values = rng.getValues();
  colors.map((r,i)=>r.map((c,j)=>{
    if(c=='#34a853'){
    values[i][j]="g";
    }}));
  rng.clearContent();
  rng.setValues(values);   
}
```